# Multiple instances of Service across AppDomains

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

So I'm trying to set up a logger in an application with multiple AppDomains. I want to create one central store in memory for all logged messages to go into. I've decided to go with a WCF named pipe binding, and I've created a log4net appender which creates a channel and sends all log events to the main service.

The problem is that I seem to get a new copy of the service in each AppDomain, and thus my single log ends up being multiple logs.

The setup is I have a service contract interface, **ILogSink**, and a singleton (actual singleton, and InstanceContextMode set to Single in Service Behavior attribute) service implementation **ResultLog** which has a collection for the logged messages. In my parent AppDomain I instantiate **ServiceHost** with **ResultLog**, and Open the service. Then I attach an Appender **WcfResultAppender**, which has a proxy copy of **ILogSink** created via a ChannelFactory CreateChannel call (to the service host address). On startup, each child AppDomain creates its own copy of WcfResultAppender.

I'm very new to WCF, what am I missing?

EDIT: I still haven't received any good responses to this - I've put the problem aside for now, but it is a pressing need. It seems as if I'm getting a different copy of my service class in each app domain, and for some reason the data is being left in those objects. I expected that there was something in the background that used the binding to resolve with the service created in the main appdomain and pass the data in via that, but something else is happening. I have read countless explanations and examples of WCF - one thing I noticed was none of the examples provide services which retain data. However I still can find nothing that contradicts or confirms my expectations.

Comment: How are you hosting your singleton?

Comment: For the time being there is a handler class which has a reference to the singleton service as well as an individual AppDomain. I'm instantiating the singleton as well as the service host in the handler. Eventually I'll refactor this to start and host the singleton above this level, but right now I'm testing with a single created handler / appdomain.

Answer (score 1):

Each AppDomain is an isolated environment, they have no direct interaction with each other.

Consider exposing your service via IIS or WAS which will run it in its own (single) AppDomain.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx for details of how to host a WCF service in IIS.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733109.aspx for details of how to host a WCF service in WAS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I guess I'm misunderstanding something basic about how this works, then. My expectation is that I was setting up a single service to listen at the named pipe location, and then by opening a channel to that service via the named pipe uri, connecting to that service independently of any appdomain or even application. Can you explain what really goes on if this is not the case? It would seem to defeat the purpose of an independent service if the clients are context dependent...

Comment: @badlander The ServiceHost class allows you to expose a service when you are not hosting it in IIS or WAS [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx), it does not figure out which other service implementations are currently being hosted in a different AppDomain. You are creating and hosting a single service instance per AppDomain.

Comment: @badlander For a useful resource on WCF see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/wcf/info

Answer (score 0):

Consider the usage of Message Queueing as storage of your log messages